# Acessar uma propriedade de um objeto salvo no localstorage

Tags: angular, typescript

Após realizar o login, eu salvo no meu localStorage o id e token de um usuário através de um objeto que nomeio de currentUser.

Como eu posso acessar a propriedade id e token desse objeto ao recuperar pelo localStorage?

O que eu tentei:

```
var USUARIO = localStorage.getItem('currentUser')
const TOKEN = JSON.parse(USUARIO.id);
const CLIENT_ID = JSON.parse(USUARIO.token);
```

porém eu recebo:

> "Property 'id' does not exist on type 'string'"

Tem alguma forma de recuperar esse objeto e atribuir pra variável token e client_id?

Comment: já inspecionou a variável USUARIO para ver como está, se tem a propriedade?

Comment: Acho que no **setItem** tem que passar como objeto, tipo `localStorage.setItem('valores', JSON.stringify(object));`

Comment: [`getItem` retorna uma string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem#Return_value), então a forma de transformá-la em um usuário vai depender de como ele foi gravado lá. Assumindo que ele foi gravado como um JSON, bastaria fazer `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'))` - e aí vc não precisa chamar o `parse` na hora de pegar o id e token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro dá a dica: a variável `USUARIO` é uma string. Você deve convertê-la antes:

```
var USUARIO = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
const TOKEN = USUARIO.id;
const CLIENT_ID = USUARIO.token;
```